# Forward some traffic through docker image?

Tags: networking, ssh, vpn, proxy, docker

My VPN runs in a docker container. I recently switched to Mac, which made this problematic, since docker for Mac does not support `--network host`. I now have to run all my VPN needs in docker containers and use `--network container:vpn`. Is it possible to set up a proxy or some other mechanism which allows the docker container to accept http, ssh and other network traffic which the system doesn't know what to do with? The end goal is to allow apps like Safari to access units on the VPN without disrupting my usual network access.